# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade to a javax.servlet.ServletRequest

Tags: java, exception, servlets, classcastexception

I am attempting to cast a org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade object to it's base type of javax.servlet.ServletRequest however; I keep getting this error..

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade cannot be cast to javax.servlet.ServletRequet
```

My code looks like like this..

```
ServletRequest httpServletRequest = (ServletRequest)paramValues[0];
            String jsonString = IOUtils.toString(httpServletRequest.getInputStream());

String methodType = httpServletRequest.getMethod();
           String contentType = httpServletRequest.getContentType();
```

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: What's in `paramValues[0]`? Doesn't seem standard. Can you perhaps show the method signature as well?

Comment: Try to run it in debug mode and see what's the type of `paramValues[0]` and its value. Clearly you have problems with casting type for this object. Maybe you're casting wrong object? Is the cast really needed here? Casting types in Java is not regular, but exceptional thing.

Comment: Which application server are you using? Also, which servlet api version is used?